# Races in answering

Tags: discussion, answers

Stack Overflow is a great place. Somebody finds it as a knowledge base, and for somebody it is a competition.

Truly say, I like Reputation. It is a great motivator for clear and useful answers and questions.

But here are my questions:

- Is there any opinions, observations (or maybe statistics) how profitable it is to answer question as fast as possible just because user wants to fetch as much as possible reputation?
- Is there any correlation between answer time and upvote count?

What is your view about such "fast" answers?

[image: Super fast answer]

Comment: Please don't make reputation your only motivator. People who try to be the fastest to answer degrade the site if the answer is poor -- though there is definitely a positive  correlation between how fast you post and the amount of upvotes -- it's gamification. In this case, the specific answer you're referring to was to a question that was a flat out homework request and it should be deleted. Fast answers to bad questions usually don't work out in the long run with many bad questions being deleted.

Comment: I did not say that reputation is my only motivator. The question is how to deal with it?

Comment: Deal with it by voting to close if the question itself is poor, and then deleting (if you have the reputation, or check out the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room where you can request deletion from other users). But if the question isn't poor and the answer is good, just because it's fast isn't a big deal.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem